# Need help when date is unix timestamp, need for current month

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with a query. I receive `NULL` as a result:

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` 
WHERE `date` BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(1438387200) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(1440979200)
```

I have tried several commands what I find here, but every command give me 
the same : `NULL` as a result, but without any errors.

Is someone know command that is working properly ?

Comment: Do you have data in there? Can you provide it?

Answer (score 1):

[UNIX_TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) in MySQL converts from a normal datetime string *into* UNIX time. The function you probably want is [FROM_UNIXTIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime).

Comment: I already tried FROM_UNIXTIME . When i search 1438387200, i receive empty result because of 00:00:00 and i dont have in table exact 1438387200. In other side when i search for 1438392609 what is same day but 01:30:09 that i receive result, but i need query for month in my case August 2015

Comment: So is your `date` column an integer and storing the UNIX time or is it in MySQL date, datetime or time format? If it's in integer format then you don't need FROM_UNIXTIME or UNIX_TIMESTAMP at all, just search using the integers.

If it's in date format, then you can select the specific part of the date you want using the datetime functions, e.g. [DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date).

Comment: So you're storing a Unix timestamp in a varchar column? If so you can either alter your database schema to use an `integer` column rather than `varchar`; or do a cast on the column.

The latter would be something like:
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONVERT(date USING UNSIGNED INTEGER) BETWEEN 1438387200 AND 1440979200;`

The former would be the same SQL just without the `CONVERT`

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this one :

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`), '%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(1438387200), '%d-%m-%Y') AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(1440979200), '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: Try this one : SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND createTime <  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY)

Comment: It is not working. Can somewhere be problem because this is MariaDB ? Some differences ?